# can gulp task call another exported task?

Tags: gulp

I am using Node.js v12.13.0, gulp 4.0.2. Assume my gulpfile.js is:

```
const gulp = require( 'gulp' );  
const { series, parallel } = require( 'gulp' );  

function task1(cb) {...}  
function task2(cb) {...}  
function task3(cb) {...}  
function task4(cb) {...}   

exports.task1 = task1;  
exports.task2 = task2;  
exports.task3 = task3;   
exports.task4 = task4;  
exports.mid = series(task1, parallel(task2, task3));
```

and I can't do the following

```
export.default = series(mid, task4);
```

Is there a way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this from somewhere.  I can see why it doesn't work but not sure if there is a way to get it to work.